# Comparing two standard distributions and getting best outcome

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let's say I have 2 normal distributions

A - Mean: $\$1000,$ Variance: $100^2$

B - Mean: $\$1500,$ Variance: $300^2$

and I want to know the probability that I get more money selecting B than I will A. I know you take the difference of the mean and add the variances, make a new standard distribution using the difference of the means and the new variance, and then see the percentage greater than zero on that distribution.

Now let's say I get 20 random selections with A and only 10 random selections on B. How would I calculate the probability that the highest/most profitable selection would be from subset B?

What formulas would I use for this situation which can be used for any number of random of selections of either subset?

Comment: So you want to calculate $P(10B-20A>0)$? Any reply helps us to help you.

Comment: No, I want to calculate the probability that the largest selection from B (10 random selections in the distribution) is greater than the largest selection of A (from the 20 random samples of A).

Like if I got ($1500, $1700, $800,... $1800) from B and ($1100, $1000, $850.... $1300) from A, B would have the better result since the largest of B ($1800) is larger than the largest of A ($1300).

Comment: So $P(\max(B_1, B_2, B_3, \ldots B_{10})- \max(A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots A_{20})>0)$?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am saying

Comment: The pdf of the max-distribution is posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381212/distribution-of-maximum-of-normally-distributed-random-variables) I´m hoping that it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\bar{A}=\max\{A_1,\ldots,A_{20}\}$ and $\bar{B}=\max\{B_1,\ldots,B_{10}\}$. By independence $\Big(\bar{A},\bar{B}\Big)\sim f_{\bar{A}\bar{B}}$ where $$f_{\bar{A}\bar{B}}(a,b)=200\Big(F_{A}(a)\Big)^{19}\Big(F_{B}(b)\Big)^{9}f_{A}(a)f_{B}(b)$$ Here $A\sim N(1000,100^2)$ while $B\sim N(1500,300^2)$. You need to compute $P(\bar{B}>\bar{A})$. This equals $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_\alpha^{\infty} f_{\bar{A}\bar{B}}(\alpha,\beta)d\beta d\alpha$$ FYI: $$f_{A}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{100\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{\alpha-1000}{100}\Big)^2}$$ $$f_{B}(\beta)=\frac{1}{300\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{\beta-1500}{300}\Big)^2}$$ $$F_{A}(\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}f_{A}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\Bigg(\frac{\alpha-1000}{100\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)$$ $$F_{B}(\beta)=\int_{-\infty}^{\beta}f_{B}(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\Bigg(\frac{\beta-1500}{300\sqrt{2}}\Bigg)$$